# Kendo UI Column with html content

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, grid

I want to display HTML inside kendo UI Col, 
Below is the stackblitz 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/kendo-ui-grid-78bc3s?file=app/products.ts
what will I have to do to make the record "Chai" appear bold?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try with below code snippet.

**Existing code:-**

```
    <kendo-grid-column field="ProductName" title="Name" width="250">
    </kendo-grid-column>
```

**New code:-**

```
    <kendo-grid-column field="ProductName" title="Name" width="120">
        <ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate let-dataItem>
             <div [innerHTML]="dataItem.ProductName"></div>
        </ng-template>
    </kendo-grid-column>
```

Comment: Any idea how to use ternary operator for innerHtml? @Jayesh